# Updating date -1 from other table based on the join condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables account and transaction. 
Account has a column named 'creation_date' and transaction has a column name 'value_date'. Transaction table has a column account_id (primary key of Account).

I want to update all the creation_date of Account to value_date-1 of Transaction table where the value_date is less than the creation_date for that particular account.

This query fetches all such records:

```
SELECT 
a.value_date,
b.creation_date
FROM transaction a,
account b
WHERE a.account_id = b.account_id
AND TRUNC(a.value_date) < TRUNC(b.creation_date)
```

I just have to update a.value_date to b.creation_date-1 for the above records.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
UPDATE 
    transaction t
SET
    value_date = (
            SELECT 
                creation_date - 1
            FROM
                account a
            WHERE
                a.account_id = t.account_id
                AND TRUNC(a.creation_date) > TRUNC(t.value_date)
            )
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1
        FROM
            account a
        WHERE
            a.account_id = t.account_id
            AND TRUNC(a.creation_date) > TRUNC(t.value_date)
    );
```

And try not using [OLD-STYLE-JOIN](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) from now on

Comment: Thanks Pham, but I cannot see the table name in your query.

Comment: one more correction is needed. It should be t.old_date = t.new_date - 1.

Comment: sorry does not works, I get the following error SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly

Comment: @Sunny It seems that update statement could not run for this case when we have many `transaction` map to one `account`. Could you try the normal update using `EXISTS` in my edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
update account a
    set creation_date = (select min(value_date) - 1
                         from transactions t
                         where t.account_id = a.account_id and
                               trunc(t.value_date) < trunc(a.creation_date)
                        )
    where exists (select 1
                  from transactions t
                  where t.account_id = a.account_id and
                        trunc(t.value_date) < trunc(a.creation_date)
                 );
```

Note:  This takes into account that multiple rows in `transactions` might correspond to the same account.  It uses the smallest `value_date` for this purpose.